# SSIS Data flow - insert bulk gets really slow

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am having a problem with a SSIS data flow. We use a OleDB driver to get a table from Oracle and insert bulk in a database table in SQL Server. The Oracle database has over 15 million rows. The SQL Server table has no indexes. We begin the process by doig a truncate on the SQL Server table and reimport the data from the Oracle table.

We are in the process of migrating our SQL server. The old architecture used a SQL Server 2012 instance on a physical Windows Server 2012 with 16GB RAM, the CPU is a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz with 24 logical processors. We used SSIS version 11.0. This architecture is still up and it processes the data flow in about 10 minutes.

The new architecture is a SQL Server 2022 instance on a virtual Windows Server 2019 with 16 GB RAM, the CPU is a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 CPU @ 2.30GHz with 4 virtual processors. We now use SSIS version 16.0. It processes the dataflow in about 90 minutes, about 9 times slower than our old physical server.

On the new server, the I/O on disk starts high (about 3,000,000 B/sec) for the first 3-4 millions rows loaded and slows down progressively to about 200,000 B/sec after reaching 3-4M rows. The CPU is about at 30% on the new server (less than 10% on the old one) and the RAM used is at 5/16GB (13/16 GB on the old server).

The same thing happens if I run the data flow on my own computer, connected to the server or if I run the job on the SQL agent directly on the new SQL Server.

I checked the data flow properties, we did not use the AutoAdjustBufferSize on the old architecture, all the buffer values were the default values. I tried changing them and deploy on the new server, but it does not improve the performance of the SSIS job.

Comment: Can you provide (a lot) more information about the virtualization environment? With it bursting at 3MB/sec and settling to 0.2MB/sec it sounds like an IOPS provisioning issue, sector alignment of the volume, or inappropriate cluster size/alignment of the file system partition(s).

Comment: There could be a bottleneck in a number of places. It could be the Oracle server can't feed the data fast enoough. It could be SSIS buffers. It could be SQL isn't fast enough. To help isolate, you could try dumping Oracle data to a flat file then BCP that into SQL Server. This breaks the data migration process up into pieces and might help isolate the cause

Comment: Check your batch size for your SSIS oracle connector, or if its a buffer setting, check the buffer size. It may be at the default of 100 rows per fetch whereas the older setup may have customized it to something higher like 10,000 rows per fetch. If it's a buffer setting make it 10x or maybe even 100x bigger. On a slowish network that can make a big difference at high data volumes.

Comment: As the other wise minds have commented, a lot more information is needed. Yet another place to look at is SQL Server itself. It could be the case that you have unhelpful processes running, like auto shrink and poor growth defaults for the log file. A quick way to identify throughput is to remove your current destination and replace it with anything. I favor a row count component. Deploy that to the server and run. When the package completes, you know it took N minutes to pull M rows from Oracle and transfer to the SSIS execution server. Does it remain 10 minutes or much less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the cause of this latency. I wanted to share the solution if anyone finds themselves entangled in a similar problem.

It seems that the version 19c of our Oracle client installed on our new SQL server was not aligned with the version of our Oracle database, which is still at version 11g. We first installed a version 12c client, which resulted in a performance gain of about 40%.

We then installed version 11g of the Oracle client, and the performance gain, compared with version 19c of the client, is now over 90%. It's now faster than our old architecture.